# Customise HTML-Kit Tools syntax highlighting

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting

I'm using HTML-Kit tools to edit a PHP site. The syntax highlighting's really helpful, but it would be good if I could edit it, specifically so that my custom functions would be highlighted (as opposed to just the built-in PHP functions). Is there any way of doing this?